# Почему скачанный через Composer пакет и тот, что в репозитории не соответствуют друг другу?

Tags: composer

1. Перехожу на страницу нужного пакета:
   https://packagist.org/packages/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis
2. Устанавливаю:

   composer require colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis
3. Открываю нужный файл и вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Перехожу в источник:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. И вижу, что здесь несколько иначе выглядит код (что, собственно, на проекте и требуется):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Почему скачанный пакет отличается от того, что в исходниках?

Comment: Почему бы не спросить об этом автора пакета?

Comment: У вас пакет установлен версии 1.14.1, а исходники на github'e показываете из ветки master. Да, содержимое у них может различаться.